# SPFx Yeoman Generator not Showing SharePoint 2019 Option

Tags: sharepoint, yeoman, spfx, yeoman-generator, sharepoint-2019

I am trying to develop my spfx web part for Sharepoint 2019/SE. Although I found an issue, and after I run command to create a SharePoint solution, there is no Sharepoint 2019 option, and only 2 of them are available. [yo sharepoint generator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t8GS6.png)

I double checked the packages, and here is a list of my versions
+-- @microsoft/generator-sharepoint@1.10.0
+-- gulp-cli@2.3.0
`-- yo@3.1.1
node -v: v8.17.0
[packages list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DY9Bq.png)

Also I am using Windows 10 if that matters

I followed this guide to configure my dev environment https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8nLDGSnYRdY

What I tried?
I changed packages of @microsoft/generator-sharepoint to 1.4.1, 1.5.1, 1.11.1, 1.12.1 and many more. Still facing same issue. Can this version be cached or can it still use old version of it somehow?
I changed packages version of node.js
I tried different yo package

Do you have any idea, why there is no Sharepoint 2019 option to target?